# Remote Win 10 clients not communicating with ubuntu LAMP server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote, lamp, ddns

Thank you in advance for assisting me. I have three nodes on a NW. Node 1 is a LAMP server on Virtual Box (VB) and node 2 the computer hosting VB. These two nodes form a LAN connected via my ISPs R218h router. Node three is a separate computer routing through a hotspot on a Galaxy S10. VPN clients are installed on all nodes. DDNS (I have a .com domain) is activated on the LAMP server as well as SSH and VNC4Server.
The situation is as such:
- I can use any client such as WinSCP, TightVNC, HeidiSQL, etc or my browser to connect to the server on my LAN - no problem.
- I can ping and tracert (from node 2 and 3)/traceroute (from node 1) between all nodes.
- DDNS is working 100% - the VPN public IP gets updated.

- All nodes have static internal ip addresses - no DHCP.
- DNS tests correct, except for "cannot load home page" (DMARC and DNSSEC tests passes).
  I cannot get access from node 3 (the external computer) to my LAMP server. I want to establish a LAN for development purposes.
  I have done the following:
- Ensured that it is not my firewall - switched it off for a trial;
- Ensured that it is not my antivirus package - switched it off for a trial on Win nodes 2 and 3;
- Ensured that file sharing is correctly set on all Win nodes 2 and 3 and that all Win/Internet features related to remote/NW is set;
- Used the VPN DNS servers for all nodes;
- Did MAC filtering on my R218h router for the internal LAN nodes - Nodes 1 and 2 (For the LAN);
- Ensured that node 3 is visible as a device to the hotspot on the Galaxy S10 - tracert and ping successfully through it;
- Ensured that browser on node 2 and 3 do not block unsecure content - for the time of testing;
- No DNS leakage with dnsleaktest.com - had blocking issues in the past from ISP;
- Whitelisted ports 21, 22, 443, 3306, 5901, 5902 on the LAMP server;
- Have set 755 permissions on /var/www/html;
  I have no idea how to proceed further? Can someone please assist me?

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm)